# AWS Credentials file not getting picked up by the Provider Chain

Tags: java, macos, amazon-web-services, centos6, aws-sdk

I'm having issues getting aws credentials set up on. I'm getting the same issues on MacOSX and CentOS 6.3. I would prefer to keep the credentials in the ~/.aws/credentials file as mentioned in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-setup.html#java-dg-install-sdk but after putting the credentials in the form of

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = your_access_key_id
aws_secret_access_key = your_secret_access_key
```

I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:77)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2853)
```

The java code I am using to set up my s3Client is as follows:

```
s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
```

Even after setting the credentials file path manually, it's not working either:

```
export AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=/home/myuser/.aws/credentials
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I had an old version of the aws java sdk in my pom file that I forgot to update. Works great since I updated it to the latest.

Comment: I am also getting the same issue , can you tell me where and what java SDk version i should put

Comment: @Awadesh I would just use the latest aws sdk from Amazon. Looks like right now that's 1.11.264. Put it in your Maven pom as a dependency if you're using Maven.

Comment: @creftos Thanks a lot, I will try this